# Why PHP echo in `background-image:ulr()` always get an escape character?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My code always got this problem:

```
<?php
  $imgurl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png";
  $get_style = 'background-image: url(\''.$imgurl.'\'); ';
?>
<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="<?php echo $get_style; ?>background-position: center center;background-attachment: inherit;">
```

But whatever I do, the html always shows:

```
<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png&quot;); background-position: center center; background-attachment: inherit;">
```

I also tried:

```
<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $imgurl ?>);background-position: center center;background-attachment: inherit;">
```

But no use at all!

Can anyone help me? TAT

Thanks for your help, but seems my and your codes all work fine in this single file:https://api.mashiro.top/cover/test.php , but always get the escape character in my production site (the same HTML id as the cover image): https://2heng.xin/ , really strange, and could be any possibility that other parts get wrong in my site?

I don't know why `style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.jpg&quot;);"` could show images in my browesr (Chrome & Firefox), but this is not a good expression ugh?

Comment: try [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: @Marko Paju Still not work... And my PHP file is in ANSI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just remove the single quotes on your `$get_style` variable.

```
<?php
  $imgurl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png";
  $get_style = 'background-image: url('.$imgurl.');';
?>
<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="<?php echo $get_style; ?>background-position: center center;background-attachment: inherit;height:100%;">
```

And it seems your site is using WordPress, so this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/something-is-unescaping-all-html-entities-before-output-to-browser) might help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix `double-quotes` and `single-quotes` for this situation:

```
<?php
  $imgurl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png";
  $get_style = "background-image: url('".$imgurl."'); "; 
?>
<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="<?php echo $get_style; ?>background-position: center center;background-attachment: inherit;">
```

Comment: I really don't understand why, the same code as yours, works fine in this single php file:https://api.mashiro.top/cover/test.php but get the escape character in my site (the same html tag id, the cover image actually): https://2heng.xin/

Answer (score 0):

Just us this.

```
<?php 
   $imgurl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png";
   $get_style = "background-image: url('".$imgurl."');";
?>
```

You also can take a look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php if you still face the same issue.

Comment: I really don't understand why, the same code as yours, works fine in this single php file:https://api.mashiro.top/cover/test.php but get the escape character in my site (the same html tag id, the cover image actually): https://2heng.xin/ LAL

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - I use this method a lot without issues.

```
<?php $imgurl = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/example.png'; ?>

<figure id="centerbg" class="centerbg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $imgurl; ?>'); background-position: center center; background-attachment: inherit;">
```